# Pharo Smalltalk LinkedList possible anomaly

Tags: data-structures, smalltalk, pharo

I think there is a bug in implementing the at:put: LinkedList method.

I detected the problem when using the Stack class, a descendant of LinkedList. When using the at:put: method to assign a value to the last element of the list, other elements disappeared from the list. This happened when the latter element pointed to some other already in the list. I am in doubt whether it is a bug or a feature.

```
s := LinkedList new.
x := (NewValueHolder value: 99).
s 
    add: (NewValueHolder value: 99);
    add: x;
    add: (NewValueHolder value: 99);
    add: (NewValueHolder value: 99).
s at: 4 put: x.
s
```

After running the list contains only 2 elements and not 4 as expected, I think.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. See the comment in `#at:putLink:`, it reads _Please don't put a link which is already in the list, or you will create an infinite loop_. Consider `#at:put:` as private in this class.

Comment: I do not know ... It's in the 'accessing' protocol and not in the 'private' protocol. And there are no comments on the 'at: put:' method (Pharo 7).

Comment: I think that's the "anomaly". The method should be classified as private.

Comment: But do you know any specification for a linked list that establishes this behavior that I pointed out as expected?

Comment: A `LinkedList` is expected to _efficiently_ support insertion and deletion messages such as `#add:`, `#add:before:`, `#add:after:`, `addFirst:` and `#remove:`, `#removeFirst` and `#removeLast`. It is also expected to support some enumeration message such as `#do:`, from which you can derive messages for selection, rejection and collection. Clients are not supposed to use low level messages such as `#at:put:`. In fact, _the whole point of the_ `LinkedList` _abstraction is to free clients from having to care about implementation details._

Comment: The hypothesis that the method LinkedList>>at:put: is for private use can not resist the fact that it is never used by any other method of the LinkedList class.

Comment: Also, the LinkedList>>at:putLink: method is only used by the method LinkedList>>at:put:.

Answer (score 2):

Let's summarize what's in the comments.

1. A `LinkedList` is a `SequenceableCollection` optimized for insertion and deletion (of elements) at any position.
2. Elements inside a `LinkedList` are automatically wrapped inside of `ValueLink` objects, which hold the original object in their `value` ivar and can be linked to the next element in the list, if any. This happens when the `LinkedList` receives any of the following messages:

`add:`, `add:after:`, `add:before:` `addFirst:` and `addLast:`.

which accept as arguments both regular objects and `Links`.

3. Two other *public* messages provided for addition are:

`add:afterLink:` and `addBeforeLink:`

4. The protocol for removing elements consists of:

`remove:ifAbsent:`, `removeAll`, `removeAllSuchThat:`, `removeFirst` and `removeLast`

Both `remove:`, `removeAllSuchThat:` are *dual* in the sense that the element to be removed can be the object wrapped in a `Link` or the `Link` itself. Other methods such as `remove:` are inherited from `SquenceableCollection`, or above.

5. The methods for enumeration are the usual for collections (all of which essentially derive from `#do:`) and are, once again, dual (see above).

Other methods for accessing, such as `at:put:`, `at:putLink:`, `atLink:`, etc. should be considered `private`, as they rely on implementation details that are not of the concern of clients.

---

Back to the question, the proper way to add the element `x` at position 4 would have been

```
s add: x before: s lastLink
```

instead of `s at: 4 put: x`.